# Unable to start the server

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am trying to use nodemon for auto-starting the server whenever a change is made in the local file, but I get the following error.

[image: CMD Window]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "myapp", 
    "version": "0.0.0", 
    "private": true, 
    "scripts": {
        "start": "if [[ $NODE_ENV == 'production' ]]; then node ./bin/www; else nodemon ./bin/www; fi"
    }, 
    "dependencies": {
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3", 
        "debug": "~2.6.9", 
        "express": "~4.16.0", 
        "http-errors": "~1.6.2", 
        "morgan": "~1.9.0", 
        "pug": "^2.0.3"
    }, 
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error to be directly visible in the question without following a link, preferably as text and not an image as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the start script uses Bash scripting syntax, but the screenshot is of a Windows command terminal. The error is because Windows doesn't understand the Bash syntax.

To immediately get you running, you can just change the start script to just `nodemon ./bin/www`. You'll then want to either figure out the correct syntax, or add another script for the production start script, like  `"start-prod": "node ./bin/www"' and run`npm run start-prod` in production.